# Devise rubygem - How do you filter actions for authenticated/non-authenticated users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am new to Rails and I need to create a simple Rails project with these conditions:

- there must be page with some articles (title + body)
- anyone can read those articles
- only authenticated users can create/edit/delete those articles

I used scaffold to generate a controller for articles and the gem Devise to create the authentication system. But I dont know how to implement the necessary conditions.

Thanks for the reply.

Comment: If I am understanding correctly - you are trying to get authentication working?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Although you did describe your problem, it is greatly appreciated to be able to see some code. Consider adding some code so that your question will have a much higher value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your user model is called `user`, then you would include the following in your controller:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

If it not called `user`, you would replace the word user in `authenticate_user` with whatever it is.

You would add this directly under your controller declaration, like so:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate_user!

  #rest of code

end
```

If you want to restrict only certain actions in the controller to logged in users, you can use `except` to exclude some actions. Here, index and show can be seen by anyone:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:index, :show]
```

or `only` to include specific actions. Here, only authenticated users can do the listed actions:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, 
              :only => [:new, :edit, :create, :update, :delete]
```